# Darth Vader with his mask off: was that David Prowse?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, is that the back of David Prowse's head that we see in the hyperbaric chamber before Darth Vader is fitted with his mask?

[image: Image from theforce.net]

Comment: I seriously doubt it. There is no reason it would have to be him. His height / stature is irrelevant to this shot without other characters around for perspective. Also, special make-up effects shots like this often do not need the actor, since their likeness is meaningless in this context.

Comment: @MeatTrademark ... for that matter, it could also be just a prop and not a real person at all.

Comment: @Paulster2 I already made that point. "...special make-up effects shots like this often do not need the actor..."

I said you didn't need the actor. Not sure how that was not clear.

Comment: @MeatTrademark ... yes you said that, but it implies it is a *different* actor. ( "... often do not need *the* actor ..." not *an* actor) My point is, as stated, it doesn't even require that.

Comment: Why isn't this closed... pure trivia question

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it ***was*** Dave Prowse playing Vader in that scene.
He had the prosthetics adhered to the back of his head for the shoot.

Here is a rare photo of Dave on set in the meditation chamber - I believe it comes from the recent J. Rinzler 'making of' book.

[image]

Comment: "Yes, it was Dave Prowse playing Vader in that scene. He had the prosthetics adhered to the back of his head for the shoot." I disagree. That doesn't even look like the meditation chamber. And I believe he wore that head cover to make the helmet more comfortable. It's obviously not a bald cap that he's wearing in that photo.

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Empire (it may have been [Bob Anderon](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0026428/)), but the unmasked Darth Vader (Return of the Jedi) is not played by David Prowse. The actor in question there is [Sebastian Shaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Shaw_%28actor%29).